# What is best LaTeX editor for win7?

Tags: editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

What is best LaTeX editor for windows 7?
I'm searching for best and perfect editor for Latex based on Windows 7.

Comment: Looks very much like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides to me!

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270121/best-latex-editor-for-windows

Comment: There is *no* best editor. There is only one that is *best for you*. To find out which one is up to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Joseph and Mohammad mentioned, there are quite many possibilities. The one you choose is all a question of taste.

If you use TeX Live, TeXworks comes with it, so it would be easy, to use this one, as you don't have to install anything. But as mentioned, you can use nearly everything, that comes in mind.

Try different ones to find out which one fits best for your needs. The *best* is always depending one the user ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm arab, and i want an editor that support `right-to-left` language. I have problem with `texworks`.

Comment: @AsgharUst: That’s an essential information, that would have belonged in your question! Search for Unicode aware editors, but honestly I’m not sure, if this is enough or whether there are other things to mind.